# Showing a substitution reduces a differential equation to a separable one

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Suppose $M(x,y)dx + N(x,y)dy = 0$ is a homogeneous equation. Show that the substitution $x = vy$ reduces the equation to one with separable variable.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you know how to start?

Answer (score 0):

If the differential equation is homogenous then we may rewrite it in the form
$$y'=f(\frac{y}{x})$$ 
and so $y'=xv'+v$ and the equation becomes
$$xv'+v=f(v)\implies \int\frac{dv}{f(v)-v}=\int\frac{dx}{x}$$

Comment: Sorry i saw the substitution as $y=xv$, but you could switch the solution knowing the $x'=1/y'$

Comment: For all $x \neq 0$